# Loading different classes dependant on list contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

I have three classes which I want to call and save them dependant on list contents. I want to figure out how to call two classes and call values within tow classes and save them, when I want to call them later, that classes remember and display what a user has been selected.

**The code:**

```
_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = 'Data_id'
        self.first = 'Data_1'
        self.second = 'Data_2'
        self.third = 'Data_3'

class Value(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = 'Value_id'
        self.first = 'Value_1'
        self.second = 'Value_2'
        self.third = 'Value_3'


class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.item = -1
        if self.item == 1 or self.item == 2:
            self.first_class = Data()
            self.second_class = Value()
            print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.first_class.second))
            print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.second_class.first))
        elif self.item == 2 or self.item == 4:
            self.first_class = Data()
            self.second_class = Value()
            print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.first_class.first))
            print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.second_class.third))
        else:
            self.first_class = Data()
            self.second_class = Value()
            print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.first_class.ID))
            print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.second_class.ID))

run = Base()
for i in _list:
    run.item = _list[i]
```

_list values changes every time, it could be None or any int number from 0 to 9 for example. The idea is to call two classes `Data and Value` every time an item from list is initialized. Then the values within the classes are called for example item 1 is called then the tow classes run and values are called.

```
        print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.first_class.first))
        print('Item:', self.item, 'Class_ID: {}'.format( self.second_class.third))
```

After execution of for-loop, user want to run following code or to know which values from which class is called at item = 3

```
run.item = _list[3]
```

How can I achieve this behaviour?
I appreciate any help. In advance thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`___init___` is a special method which supposed to run exactly once when the class is initialized. When you call `run = Base()` the logic runs, `self.item` will be evaluated as `-1`

What your class does is basically this:

```py
controls = [0,1]

class Controlled:
     def __init__(self):
        self.param = -1
        if self.param == 0:
            print(0)
        elif self.param == 1:
            print(1)
        else:
            print('This is not unexpected')

c = Controlled()
for p in controls:
    c.param = p
```

If you run `Controlled()`, the `self.param` will be `-1` every time during the initialization, the `else` branch will print the `This is not unexpected` message. The

```py
for p in controls:
    c.param = p
```

part basically just updates the class attribute but does not call anything, nothing will be printed or executed.

---

I think you wanted to implement something like this:

```
controls = [0,1]

class Controlled:
    def __init__(self, param=-1):
        self.param = param
        if self.param == 0:
            print(0)
        elif self.param == 1:
            print(1)
        else:
            print('This is not unexpected')

results = []

for p in controls:
    results.append(Controlled(p))
```

When you call `__init__(self, param=-1)`, the given parameter (`p`) will be taken into account and the init logic will run based on the given parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and correction. I'm also thinking saving in a list or dictionary  for each run.